# Debugging IIS 7 errors on shared hosting

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, fastcgi

I have a few Drupal sites (PHP) around on Windows shared hosting. I frequently run into IIS 7 errors when re-installing an entire site at which point I'm totally stuck. Then I have to open a support ticket with my hosting provider which takes a  while to get resolved (a couple of hours) and the never tell me what they did to fix it. I'm looking for more resources or checklists to narrow things down and try to resolve the issues myself (and don't lose hours).

The errors most often contain these bits:

```
Module: FastCgiModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: PHP_via_FastCGI
```

There's also an error code but usually that's just 0 (`0x00000000`).

I only have access by FTP and and a web administration tool (WebSitePanel if it makes any difference). Most of the time uploading a testpage which dumps `phpinfo()` does work so I have more info available...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you in WebsitePanel to get more information about an exact problem. Your web hosting provider may need to check server logs -> Application logs from their server and find out root cause of this problem.